# Web.config error (system.serviceModel)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, web-config

Any help why this error happens?

Thank you!!!

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'cookieManager'
>   cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is
>   registered in the extension collection at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions. Parameter name:
>   element

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EnableCookieManager">
          <cookieManager/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="cookieManager" type="App1.Web.Cookie.CookieManagerBehaviorExtension, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

[This](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfcookiemanager/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2240) example have been used.

Comment: Just a guess, but I would say that you need the extension registration before the behaviors section. aka. Swap behaviors and extensions order in the config.

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure the type name is exactly equivalent to typeof(CookieManagerBehaviorExtension).AssemblyQualifiedName

Also, if you use the WCFService Config Editor to add the behavior extension, you can just browse for the DLL & class and it then sets all the proper information to your configuration file, just in case you got it slightly wrong?